# jQuery keep ratio when size is changing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to change dynamically the width and height which are mentionned in the iframe, so in the textarea. To do this, I use two input text and try to recover values in real time. Also, I would like to keep ratio when the value of the width or the height is changing.

https://jsfiddle.net/nadir10/v7heodzm/

**HTML**

```
<form id="generation_lien" action="/">
   <textarea id="embed_code" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
   <label>Size :</label>
   <input id="width_iframe" type="text" value="640" />
   <span>×</span>
   <input id="height_iframe" type="text" value="360" />
   <span>pixels</span>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
function calculateFrameWidth(){return $('#width_iframe').val();}
function calculateFrameHeight(){return $('#height_iframe').val();}
$("#width_iframe").keyup(function()
{
   widthIframe = calculateFrameWidth();
   /*heightIframe = widthIframe / 1.77777778;*/
});
$("#height_iframe").keyup(function()
{
  heightIframe = calculateFrameHeight();
  /*widthIframe = heightIframe * 1.77777778;*/
});
var widthIframe = calculateFrameWidth();
var heightIframe = calculateFrameHeight();
document.getElementById('embed_code').innerHTML = '<iframe id="iframe_link" src="mysite/iframe.php" width="'+widthIframe+'" height="'+heightIframe+'></iframe>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate ratio of size by `Width / Height`.

```js
var firstWidth = $("#width_iframe").val();
var firstHeight = $("#height_iframe").val();
var ratio = firstWidth / firstHeight;
setSize(firstWidth, firstHeight);

$("#width_iframe").on("keyup change", function(){
    var width = $(this).val();
    $("#height_iframe").val(width / ratio);
    setSize(width, $("#height_iframe").val());
});

$("#height_iframe").on("keyup change", function(){
    var height = $(this).val();
    $("#width_iframe").val(height * ratio);
    setSize($("#width_iframe").val(), height);
});

function setSize(widthIframe, heightIframe){
    $("#embed_code").text('<iframe id="iframe_link" src="mysite/iframe.php" width="'+widthIframe+'" height="'+heightIframe+'"></iframe>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="embed_code" readonly="readonly" style="width:100%"></textarea>
<label>Size :</label>
<input id="width_iframe" type="text" value="640" />
<span>×</span>
<input id="height_iframe" type="text" value="360" />
<span>pixels</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by changing the width/height of the iFrame to whatever values you want, like this:

```
$("#embed_code").css({
  width: widthIframe,
  height: heightIframe
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as keyup event is concerned you can usage the below code.

```
$("#width_iframe").on('keyup',function()
{
    alert("Width");
  widthIframe = calculateFrameWidth();
  /*heightIframe = widthIframe / 1.77777778;*/
});

$("#height_iframe").on('keyup',function()
{
 alert("Height");
  heightIframe = calculateFrameHeight();
  /*widthIframe = heightIframe * 1.77777778;*/
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change minimum from your code. If you want to update the values keeping the ration, then you need to store the previous values. I do that on updateTextAreaContent by creating data-prev-width/height attribute on the textarea. I think your code is almost right except you didnt call the updateTextAreaContent every time keyup occurs. cheers :)

```js
function calculateFrameWidth() {
  return parseFloat($('#width_iframe').val());
}

function calculateFrameHeight() {
  return parseFloat($('#height_iframe').val());
}

function updateWidthAndHeight(width, height) {
  $('#width_iframe').val(width);
  $('#height_iframe').val(height);
}

function getPrevWidthAndHeight() {
  return {
    width: parseFloat($('#embed_code').attr("data-prev-width")),
    height: parseFloat($('#embed_code').attr("data-prev-height"))
  }
}

$("#width_iframe").keyup(function(e) {
  console.log(e);

  widthIframe = calculateFrameWidth();
  heightIframe = calculateFrameHeight();
  var prevWidthAndHeight = getPrevWidthAndHeight();
  var newHeight = widthIframe / prevWidthAndHeight.width * heightIframe;
  console.log(prevWidthAndHeight);
  updateWidthAndHeight(widthIframe, newHeight);
  updateTextAreaContent();
  /*heightIframe = widthIframe / 1.77777778;*/
});

$("#height_iframe").keyup(function(e) {

  widthIframe = calculateFrameWidth();
  heightIframe = calculateFrameHeight();
  var prevWidthAndHeight = getPrevWidthAndHeight();
  var newWidth = heightIframe / prevWidthAndHeight.height * widthIframe;
  console.log(prevWidthAndHeight);
  updateWidthAndHeight(newWidth, heightIframe);
  updateTextAreaContent();
  /*widthIframe = heightIframe * 1.77777778;*/
});

function updateTextAreaContent() {
  var widthIframe = calculateFrameWidth();
  var heightIframe = calculateFrameHeight();
  $('#embed_code').attr("data-prev-width", widthIframe);
  $('#embed_code').attr("data-prev-height", heightIframe);
  document.getElementById('embed_code').innerHTML = '<iframe id="iframe_link" src="mysite/iframe.php" width="' + widthIframe + '" height="' + heightIframe + '"></iframe>';
}

//init textarea
updateTextAreaContent();
```

```css
#embed_code {
  width: 550px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="generation_lien" action="/">
  <textarea id="embed_code" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
  <label>Size :</label>
  <input id="width_iframe" type="text" value="640" />
  <span>×</span>
  <input id="height_iframe" type="text" value="360" />
  <span>pixels</span>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank's for you answer.